# How to identify exactly where exception occurred in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

In Jenkins pipeline build, sometimes I've seen null pointer or other exceptions like -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method trim() on null object
```

Generally if we run Java program through IDE or command line, if an exception occurs we see at which line number the exception has occurred.

But with Jenkins build output console, it does not show the line number where the exception has occurred.

In this case, based on method name ie `trim()` from log, I check wherever `trim()` method is used. But as I've used it at multiple places in same method, it becomes difficult to identify exactly where error has occurred.

Another way is to add echo statements and re-run build and see where it gives this exception but this is time consuming.

Is there any better way/plugin using which I can identify at which line of pipeline code exception has occurred?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if it's possible to show the exact line number, but you can wrap your code in `try-catch` statements and then show the exception info in the catch, like so:

```
try {
    // line with trim()
catch (ex) {
    println "Exception while trimming: $ex"
}
```

Comment: Yes this can be done when we know when exactly exception occurs but I don't know in advance at which line exception occur and adding try-catch at every line is not a good apporach